# Let's hope there will be snow!

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking, geography

A week ago, my parents told me that we will be going abroad<sup>1</sup> for Christmas holidays, but they did not clarify to which country.

Today, I found a note under the windshield wiper of my car. I recognised my mother's handwriting, but all the note said was:

> liar near son in a thorn

Well, it doesn't speak for itself... Can you help me guess **in which country** I am going for Christmas?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I am French, so you can already cross a country off the map.</sub>

---

Hint :

> Why the heck did she put this note under a windshield wiper, when she could have send me a text message for instance?

Comment: thorn = north, liar = rail ... you're taking a train northwards?

Comment: Not sure who downvoted here. So +1 :)

Comment: I guess, some of the letters might be hiding behind those wipers.

Comment: son in a thorn might refers to Jesus, there are a couple places named after him - Salvador / le Salvador / San Salvador

Comment: Since you are hoping for snow, is it safe to rule out tropical countries? ;)

Comment: Your mother wrote you a note *in English*?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan She knew PSE would enjoy this puzzle so... English it is!

Comment: Should this be tagged [tag:geography]?

Comment: Well, you are obviously going to Canada. Cause lets face it, anywhere else would be a big letdown :P. Also there is more snow than you can shake a shovel at XD

Comment: Were the letters from "windshield" wiped from the note? haha

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess:

> Lesotho

Based on the hint, what we need to do is to

> "Wipe" the letters that spell 'rain' from the message, which leaves us with l, e, s, o, t, h, and o, or Lesotho, a country in Southern Africa. Given the Wiki description of the place, I'm not sure you're going to find much to enjoy there.

Comment: Yes, that fits both the lateral thinking and the wordplay tag perfectly!

Comment: I got close when I commented **I guess, some of the letters might be hiding behind those wipers** :) +1

Comment: The hint basically gave it away, but the real lateral-thinking needed for me is to figure out why anyone would want to go there. :p

Comment: Well, the hint didn't do anything for me. I tried to anagram the words to a foreign expression for parking ticket. `:)`

Comment: This is it! Could you and @MOehm give me some feedback on the difficulty about this puzzle? Seems like the hint gave it away.

Comment: @IAmInPLS: The difficulty is okay, I think, but it's one of these puzzles that you either get or don't. Once you've found (or seen) the solution, it's clear. I couldn't make the mental leap to wipe the "rain" off the message, partly because I didn't see the significance of the wipers and partly because I didn't get the connection to wipe letters out, even after I'd seen the hint.

Comment: After some thought I agree that it's just one of those things you "get" or you don't. In any case it was certainly fun to solve, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'll give this a shot. You 'll go ...

> ... skiing at the **MATTERHORN**.

Why?

> The *liar* is a **MAT**, because it lies. In front of the door, that is. The *son* is **[ER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Er_(biblical_person))**, the eldest son of Judah in the Old Testament. (Yes, that's quite a stretch.) And the *thorn* is just **THORN**.
>
>  Now, *liar near son in a thorn* can be interpreted as **MAT** + **T**(**ER**)**HORN**.
>
>  The title hints at winter sports.
>
>  (But then, your mother is probably French, too, so she'd call the Matterhorn *Mont Cervin*.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for a country. I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: Also, your reasoning is way off :-)!

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't really confident this would be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess

> Iran

Reason:

> Son in a thorn sounds more like "sun in a throne". Liar feels like "Lair". So, With a bit of googling, I get [the sun throne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Throne)  .
> It was built by Persian King. So, probably, you are going to Iran.

Comment: No, you're off. Nice try though :-)

Comment: @IAmInPLS Nowhere close? Or somewhat close?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a guess.

> Is it finland?
>
>  liar near son in a thorn
>  **lies** near **sauna** **north**
>
>  I'm not sure if the OP really lives in France or not, but considering that this information would be mostly irrelevant, I can only assume it was meant as a hint. So using France as point of origin, we get directions to reach the destination. So I came up with thorn -> north -> country north of France.
>
>  **son in a** kinda sounded like **sauna** to me, although perhaps a little bit of a stretch?
>  And after a Google search, Finland seems famous for saunas(and lots of snow!)

Comment: Nice try, but France is not a hint. Well, it means that the answer is not France, but that's it! Also, not enough lateral thinking in your answer :-)...